# Python how to split a Dictionary

Tags: python, apache, dictionary, logging

Hello i have a python script which puts the time, date + ip address into a dictionary but i want to split this so i can make the output look better. The out put currently is

```
on ('Feb  4 10', '85.17.188.70') There was 2  attacks with  ('Feb  4 10', '85.17.188.70') 
on ('Feb  3 08', '211.167.103.172') There was 172  attacks with  ('Feb  3 08', '211.167.103.172') 
on ('Feb  4 08', '1.234.51.243') There was 15  attacks with  ('Feb  4 08', '1.234.51.243')
```

but i want to to say:

On Feb 4 08 Hours there was 2 attacks with IP address 85.17.188.70.

my code is as followed:

```
myAuthlog=open('auth.log', 'r')

counter_IP = 0
desc_ip = {}

for line in myAuthlog.readlines():
    list_of_line = line.split(' ')

#Start of method for attacks per hour, per IP 
#we are working backwards to avoid the difference of the length of the logs
    attack_ip_and_time = list_of_line[-4] #attack_ip_and_time is equal to   list_of_line but working backwards so will work 4 spaces back.
    attack_ip_address_list= attack_ip_and_time.split('port') #it will know split the line after the word 'port' and be called attack_ip_address_list
    attack_ip_address = attack_ip_address_list[0] #attack_ip_address is now equal to attack_ip_address_list
    perhour = line[0:9]
    if 'Failed password for' in line: # If 'Failed password for' is in the line then:
        print '\'',attack_ip_address,'\''
        print '\'', perhour, '\''
        if (perhour, attack_ip_address) in desc_ip: #if desc_ip has 'attack_ip_address' available in the dictionary then:
            count_ip = desc_ip[perhour, attack_ip_address] #count_ip equals desc_ip[attack_ip_address]
            count_ip = count_ip +1 # every time there is an occurrence the counter goes up by 1
            desc_ip[perhour, attack_ip_address] = count_ip #desc_ip[attack_ip_address] will now equal the counter     count_ip =0 #zero out the temporary counter as a precaution
        else: # if 'attack_ip_address' is not available in 'desc_ip' then:
        desc_ip[perhour, attack_ip_address] = 1 # if 'attack_ip_address' is not available in the dictionary then desc_ip[attack_ip_address] will equal 1
#End of method for attacks per hour, per IP


print '\nNumber of attacks per hour per IP:' #prints the tet
for desc_item in desc_ip.keys(): # for description items that are stored in ip dictionary
print 'on', desc_item, 'There was', desc_ip[desc_item],' attacks with ', desc_item, ''
print ''
```

is there any way i can split this dictionary in order to produce this outcome?

Example output to auth.log

```
Feb  5 08:33:15 j4-be02 sshd[2255]: Failed password for root from 5.199.133.223 port 48154 ssh2
Feb  5 08:33:23 j4-be02 sshd[2257]: Failed password for root from 5.199.133.223 port 55109 ssh2
Feb  5 08:33:30 j4-be02 sshd[2259]: Failed password for root from 5.199.133.223 port 62058 ssh2
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the dictionary please?

Comment: well inside of the dictionary is ('Feb  4 10', '85.17.188.70') the date time and IP address

Comment: I think you can improve the way you extract the time and ip from the log lines. Please post sample log messages you have inside the `auth.log`.

Comment: Feb  5 08:33:15 j4-be02 sshd[2255]: Failed password for root from 5.199.133.223 port 48154 ssh2
Feb  5 08:33:23 j4-be02 sshd[2257]: Failed password for root from 5.199.133.223 port 55109 ssh2
Feb  5 08:33:30 j4-be02 sshd[2259]: Failed password for root from 5.199.133.223 port 62058 ssh2

Answer (score 0):

the final 3 lines:

```
string_format = "on, {date}, there was {count} attacks with {ip}"
for key, count in desc_ip.iteritems():
    print string_format.format(date=key[0], count=count, ip=key[1])
```

iteritems gives you the key and the value for each element in the dictionary, the first part of the key is the date, the second part is the ip.

Comment: so I've replaced the last 'for' statement with the one you provided and i get the following error 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: my bad I mixed up itervalues with iteritems... try again with iteritems which should return the key and value

Comment: my output is 'on, {date}, there was {count} attacks with {ip}'

Comment: this is what I get for not testing I suppose, print the string as you format it or save it to a tmp string (look at edit)

Comment: that works is there any change we could also split the date and time into two separate keys?

Comment: your date is stored as a string which is a bit messy consider using strptime? tested it with `strptime('Feb  4 10', '%b  %d %H')` or if you're sure on the format you could just split it like `month = key[0][:3], day = key[0][5], hour = key[0][-2:]` but that is a different problem

Answer (score 0):

You can access the individual components of you keys with a simple number like so:

print 'on', desc_item[0], 'There was', desc_ip[desc_item],' attacks with IP address', desc_item[1], ''